# ERROR: Could not include PEAR database functions required for the database backend

Tags: php, squirrelmail

This error happen when I connect dsn in squirrel mail address book stored into mysql

Is PEAR installed, and is the include path set correctly to find DB.php? storing addressbook in squirrel mail to mysql, i am getting the error. Pls help, if any one know the solution

Answer (score 2):

You can use the system package. For example for Fedora/CentOS/Redhat :

```
sudo yum install php-pear-DB
```

Or use pear to install DB with :

```
pear install DB
```

Or download DB.php here : http://pear.php.net/package/DB/download (current last version : http://download.pear.php.net/package/DB-1.7.14.tgz ) and uncompress DB.php and the DB directory in ./squirrelmail-*/src/

Answer (score 2):

This is an old thread but I never found the real solution to the Virtualmin's Squirrelmail error:

*"Could not include PEAR database functions required for the database backend.
Is PEAR installed, and is the include path set correctly to find DB.php?
Please contact your system administrator and report this error."*

By now, Virtualmin version is 1.831 and I am on Debian 8. The standard PEAR installed by Virtualmin is version 1.9.5.

To solve this annoying problem you need to run the command:

```
pear install db
```

**This command will fail**, because the required version of PEAR for this would be 1.10.x. Now you need to update to PEAR 1.10.x which is pretty easy:

```
wget http://pear.php.net/go-pear.phar
php go-pear.phar
```

This will update PEAR, check the version with:

```
pear version
```

in my case: PEAR Version: 1.10.3

Now you can run the last command:

```
pear install db
```

It will install it and finally the error will not appear anymore.

I hope this will help somebody.

*PS. In my **working** configuration I have uncommented the following line:
;include_path=".:/usr/share/php" (should remove the leading ";")
at the following locations:
/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini
/etc/php5/cli/php.ini and restart Apache*